# Making class conform to protocol with category for existing methods

Tags: objective-c, protocols, implementation, categories

I have a protocol named MyProtocol.
MyProtocol has an required method:

```
- (NSUInteger)length;
```

And some other methods.

Now i want to make the NSString class conform to MyProtocol with a category. Like so:

```
@interface NSString (NSStringWithMyProtocol) <MyProtocol>
@end
```

In this category i implement all methods excluding the 'length' method, because i want the original NSString implementation.
I do not want to override it in this particular class.

Now i get a warning because of an incomplete implementation of MyProtocol in the category.

I know there are a few solutions to solve this.

1. Make the method optional
2. Pointer Swizzling
3. Adding subclass to class which is conform to the protocol. Then leave out the implementation.

I do not want to use these options because they result in a bad design for the rest of my code.
Option 3 is bad, because of existing direct subclasses will not be conform to the protocol.

Does anybody know how to remove the warning without implementing the length method?

**NOTE:** The class, category and protocol are just examples. I did encounter this problem with other classes which i could not post about.
Thanks

**EDIT:** Added the third option.

**Full Code:**

The protocol:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void) myMethod;
- (NSInteger) length;

@end
```

The category header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface NSString (MyProtocol) <MyProtocol>
@end
```

The category implementation:

```
@implementation NSString (MyProtocol)

- (void)myMethod {

}

@end
```

This results in the following warnings.

```
Incomplete implementation

Method in protocol not implemented
```

In this screenshot you can see my warning:
[image: Screen shot]

I tried compiling with LLVM GCC 4.2 and the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler.
I also compiled on xcode 4.0.2 and Xcode 4.2.
I'm on OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you post code that demonstrates it? The following compiles without warnings on 10.7.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (NSUInteger)length;
@end

@interface NSString (NSStringWithMyProtocol) <MyProtocol>
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    id<MyProtocol> foo = @"foo";
    NSLog(@"%@", foo);    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added my code. I also see whats different. You did not define an implementation for the category.

Comment: Clang apparently is much stricter about this than gcc. In the vast majority of cases, that's a good thing, but in this case I believe you've pushed it to the edge of the current implementation. I would open a defect against clang.

Comment: I think i will sign this as the correct answer. Note that it will only function when a class already did implement all methods defined in the protocol. The categories implementation can not exist with a partial implementation of the protocol.

Comment: This question and answer were helpful to me. I get the same warning, but my code still compiles and runs FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this a bit of a hack, and I don't know if it will even work, but how about declaring it as a read only property

```
@property (readonly, assign) NSUInteger length;
```

and then in the implementation of your category, make it `@dynamic`

Comment: Whould work for a getter, but not for the setter. Didn't indicate this was just an example. Wasn't able to talk about my production code.

Comment: True. But that will not only resolve setter/getter kind of methods. As noted in my previous comment, i deal with other classes and methods.